# Как заблокировать контролы при помощи переключателей Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть форма, на которой расположено множество гиперссылок с переходом на другую форму с теорией, где при нажатии на кнопку открывается тест.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На форме теста есть три вкладки TabControl.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Также у меня есть переключатели типа bool AnsweredQuestion1, AnsweredQuestion2 и AnsweredQuestion3 (Таких еще несколько, поскольку вопросов больше и номера переключателей соответственно равны номерам вопросов), которые становятся true или false в зависимости от того, правильно ли были введены ответы на эти вопросы. Я решил сделать такую логику, что если пользователь отвечает на вопрос правильно, то при повторной загрузке формы с тестом по выбранному разделу данный вопрос помечается решенным, баллы за него засчитываются один раз и он может пролистать дальше к тому вопросу, который был решен неправильно, чтобы до конца пройти выбранный раздел.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Однако поскольку форма одна и на нее грузятся разные вопросы с ответами из базы данных, он при полном прохождении одного из разделов помечает пройденными и все остальные разделы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хотел бы спросить, есть ли какие-либо варианты решения с самими переключателями, чтобы не менять ничего в базе и на форме, поскольку времени остается мало...
Вижу, что дело в условии, но как его лучше поменять, чтобы блокировать контролы к разным разделам не могу придумать...

```
private void TestForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label4.Visible = false;
        label5.Visible = false;
        label6.Visible = false;
        switch (Test.Theme_ID)
        {
            case 1:
                if (Test.AnsweredQuestion1 == true || Test.AnsweredQuestion4 == true || Test.AnsweredQuestion7 == true)
                {
                    radioButton1.Enabled = false;
                    radioButton2.Enabled = false;
                    radioButton3.Enabled = false;
                    radioButton4.Enabled = false;
                    label4.Visible = true;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (Test.AnsweredQuestion2 == true || Test.AnsweredQuestion5 == true || Test.AnsweredQuestion8 == true)
                {
                    textBox1.Enabled = false;
                    label5.Visible = true;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (Test.AnsweredQuestion3 == true || Test.AnsweredQuestion6 == true || Test.AnsweredQuestion9 == true)
                {
                    radioButton5.Enabled = false;
                    radioButton6.Enabled = false;
                    radioButton7.Enabled = false;
                    radioButton8.Enabled = false;
                    label6.Visible = true;
                }
                break;
        }
        Text = $"Вопросы к теме: {User.header}";
        GetData();
        Output_Data();
    }
```

Пример кнопки "далее" для считывания вариантов ответа на первой странице TabControl:

```
      private void RBnext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkCancel = false;
        if (Test.AnsweredQuestion1 == true || Test.AnsweredQuestion4 == true || Test.AnsweredQuestion7 == true)
        {
            tabControl1.SelectTab("tabPage2");
        }
        else 
        {
            if (!radioButton1.Checked && !radioButton2.Checked && !radioButton3.Checked && !radioButton4.Checked)
                MessageBox.Show("Вы не выбрали вариант ответа!", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            else
            {
                GetAnswers();
                switch (Test.Theme_ID)
                {
                    case 1:
                        if ((radioButton1.Checked && radioButton1.Text == Test.Answer1) ||
                    (radioButton2.Checked && radioButton2.Text == Test.Answer1) ||
                    (radioButton3.Checked && radioButton3.Text == Test.Answer1) ||
                    (radioButton4.Checked && radioButton4.Text == Test.Answer1))
                        {
                            if (Test.AnsweredQuestion1 == false)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Верно!");
                                User.Progress += 11.11;
                                tabControl1.SelectTab("tabPage2");
                                Test.AnsweredQuestion1 = true;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Неверно...");
                            tabControl1.SelectTab("tabPage2");
                            Test.AnsweredQuestion1 = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if ((radioButton1.Checked && radioButton1.Text == Test.Answer4) ||
                    (radioButton2.Checked && radioButton2.Text == Test.Answer4) ||
                    (radioButton3.Checked && radioButton3.Text == Test.Answer4) ||
                    (radioButton4.Checked && radioButton4.Text == Test.Answer4))
                        {
                            if (Test.AnsweredQuestion4 == false)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Верно!");
                                User.Progress += 11.11;
                                tabControl1.SelectTab("tabPage2");
                                Test.AnsweredQuestion4 = true;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Неверно...");
                            tabControl1.SelectTab("tabPage2");
                            Test.AnsweredQuestion4 = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        if ((radioButton1.Checked && radioButton1.Text == Test.Answer7) ||
                    (radioButton2.Checked && radioButton2.Text == Test.Answer7) ||
                    (radioButton3.Checked && radioButton3.Text == Test.Answer7) ||
                    (radioButton4.Checked && radioButton4.Text == Test.Answer7))
                        {
                            if (Test.AnsweredQuestion7 == false)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Верно!");
                                User.Progress += 11.11;
                                tabControl1.SelectTab("tabPage2");
                                Test.AnsweredQuestion7 = true;

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Неверно...");
                            tabControl1.SelectTab("tabPage2");
                            Test.AnsweredQuestion7 = false;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }  
    }
```

Для остальных двух вкладок код аналогичный, просто используются другие переключатели с другими номерами под номер вопроса.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что надо добавить логику такую, что переход к новому разделу вызывает сброс значений контролов. `switch (Test.Theme_ID)` из `TestForm_Load()` нужно переместить в отдельный метод и вызывать его при нажатии на кнопку Далее, если я верно понял ваш код.

Comment: @Bulson А стоит ли делать отдельное условие для каждого переключателя в данном случае?